# PL/SQL Update Join?

Tags: join, plsql

I know there is no Update-Join statement in PL/SQL. I used to write T-SQL.

I have two tables.

```
Alex_Table1
---------------------------
PK         VAL
---------------------------
1          Value1
2          Value2
3          Value3


Alex_Table2
---------------------------
PK         VAL
---------------------------
1          Value1_2
3          Value3_2
```

I want to update VAL from Alex_Table2 to Alex_Table1 joining by PK column.

In T-SQL, that is simple

```
update t1 set t1.VAL = t2.VAL
from
    Alex_Table1 t1
    inner join Alex_Table2 t2 on t1.PK = t2.PK;
```

And the result is what I expected

```
Alex_Table1
---------------------------
PK         VAL
---------------------------
1          Value1_2
2          Value2
3          Value3_2
```

My question is how to do in PL/SQL? Thanks!

**Update**

Thanks Cybernate and ypercube gave me two useful solutions. They both work. However, I want to let you know the performance between these two statements.

My actual table contains 80,000 records and only 3,000 needs update.

`MERGE` statement takes 0.533 seconds.

`UPDATE EXISTS` statement takes over 3 minutes ( I did not measure the actual time. I terminated my process after 3 minutes.)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use a MERGE statement:

```
MERGE INTO Alex_Table1 t1
USING Alex_Table2 t2
ON (t1.PK = t2.PK)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET t1.VAL = t2.VAL
```

Comment: WOW! <-- this is my only expression! Thanks! This is simple and direct! Thanks!

Comment: I have another question. In my current case, the update statement only involved two tables. Can I use MERGE statement if the update statement involved more than two tables?

Comment: You can any valid query in lieu of Alex_Table2 in the query above. Check this link for more info:  http://psoug.org/reference/merge.html

Answer (score 9):

```
UPDATE Alex_Table1 t1
SET t1.VAL =
      ( SELECT t2.VAL 
        FROM Alex_Table2 t2
        WHERE t2.PK = t1.PK
      )
WHERE EXISTS
        ( SELECT *
          FROM Alex_Table2 t2
          WHERE t2.PK = t1.PK
        )
```

This also works (as long as `(PK)` is the primary key of `Alex_Table2`):

```
UPDATE
  ( SELECT t1.VAL A, t2.VAL B
    FROM Alex_Table1 t1
      JOIN Alex_Table2 t2
        ON t2.PK = t1.PK
  )
SET A = B ;
```

Tested at **[dbfiddle.uk](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ffbf7d5fee63ea27702341c366686f30)**.

Comment: @Alex: Have a look at the second way too. Since you are familiar with JOINs, it should be pretty easy to extend an update to more than 2 tables.

Comment: Sorry, your second statement does not work. The error message is `SQL Error: ORA-00904: "T2"."VAL": invalid identifier`

Comment: @Alex: Can you try now? I don't have an Oracle machine available now to test.

Comment: It is still not working. The error message is `SQL Error: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table`

Comment: @RachSharp did you use the exact same query? Was your join based on the table's primary key?)